# Feature importance for ANN

Tags: neural-networks, classification, importance

I have a multi-class classifier ANN with ~11000 input features, two hidden layers and a softmax output.

I would like to know which features are most important to drive the network towards predicting one class vs another.

I have seen [saliency maps](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6034.pdf) used to define per-class pixel importance in convolutional networks that classify images; however, I seem to struggle to find something similar for a 1D/non-CNN case.

Can someone suggest methods to solve this problem (references and examples would be greatly appreciated!)?

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like Shapley values (or alternatives) should do the trick if you are looking for instance explanation.

https://www.yourdatateacher.com/2021/05/17/how-to-explain-neural-networks-using-shap/

The example uses a sklearn MLP but similar implementations should also exist for PyTorch and Tensorflow

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll have a look; from a first look, however, I'm left wondering about the feasibility of this approach when I have ~11k input features.

Comment: It is probably quite computationally expensiv, but it works for CNNs as well and they also have equal or more features 
https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/demystifying-neural-nets-with-shapley-values-cca29c836089